# Using Java and regular expression to fix path

Tags: java, regex, string, path, string-parsing

I have a string like this (not always the same *filename* at the end, this is only example)

```
\\eabman03\edicom\Aterlasning\repstat.txt
```

And i want to get this

```
\\eabman03\edicom\Aterlasning\
```

So I want to strip the *filename* at the end of this string with Java. How do I do this most efficient way?

Answer (score 5):

```
new File(stringValue).getParent()
```

Comment: much better than string manipulation, because File abstracts the format of the path. so, for instance, you don't have to worry about whether the 'fileSeperator' is "/" or "\\"

Comment: Don't you need a .getAbsolutePath()?

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "\\eabman03\\edicom\\Aterlasning\\repstat.txt";
System.out.println(str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf('\\')+1));
```

1. get the lastindex of `\`
2. and use String.subString() method

output:

```
\eabman03\edicom\Aterlasning\
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String dirpath = filepath.replaceAll("(?<=\\\\)[^\\]+", "")
```